# finding the total number of distinct shortest paths between 2 nodes in undirected weighted graph in linear time?

Tags: graph, distinct, shortest-path, dijkstra, bellman-ford

I was wondering, that if there is a weighted graph G(V,E), and I need to find a single shortest path between any two vertices S and T in it then I could have used the Dijkstras algorithm. but I am not sure how this can be done when we need to find all the distinct shortest paths from S to T. Is it solvable on O(n) time? I had one more question like if we assume that the weights of the edges in the graph can assume values only in certain range lets say 1 <=w(e)<=2 will this effect the time complexity?

Comment: See my answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11879166/number-of-shortest-paths-between-two-coordinate-points-in-a-graph-with-constrain/11879866#11879866

Comment: how is the distance based approach going to work in this case of weights?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using Dijkstra. In Dijkstra's algorithm, you assign labels to each node based on the distance it has from your source and settle nodes according to this distance (smallest first). Once the target node is settled, you have the length of the shortest path. To retrieve the path (=the sequence of edges), you can keep track of the parent of each node you settle. To retrieve all possible paths, you have to account for **multiple parents of each node**.

A small example:

Suppose you have a graph which looks like this (all edges weight 1 for simplicity):

```
       B
      / \
     A   C - D
      \ /
       E
```

When you do dijkstra to find the distance A->D, you would get 3. You would first settle node A with distance 0, then nodes B and E with distance 1, node C with distance 2 and finally node D with distance 3. To get the paths, you would remember the parents of the nodes when you settle them. In this case you would first set the parents of B and C =node A. You then need to set the parents of node C to B and E as they both supply the same length. Node D would get node C as a parent.

When you need the paths, you could just follow the parent pointers, starting at D and branching each time a node has multiple parents. This would give you a branch at node C.

The post mentioned in the comment above uses the same principles, although it does not allow you to actually extract the paths, it only gives you the count. 
One final remark: Dijkstra is not a linear time algorithm as you need to do a lot of operations to maintain you queue and node sets.

Answer (score 0):

(a) Using BFS from s to mark nodes visited as usual, in the meantime, changing following things:

(b) for each node v, it has a record L(v) representing the layer that v is on and a record f(v)
representing the number of incoming paths:

(c) everytime a node v1 is found in another node's v2 neighbors:

(d) if v1 is not in the queue, add it into queue, L(v1) = L(v2) + 1,f(v1)+ = f(v2)

(d) if v1 is already in the queue and L(v1) equals L(v2), do nothing.

(e) if v1 is already in the queue but L(v1) doe not equal to L(v2), f(v1)+ = f(v2)

(f) until in this modied BFS, t pop from the queue for the rst time, we have f(t)

(g) and this f(t) represents the number of dierent shortest paths from s to t

This might solve your problem.