# The number of shortest path between two nodes

Tags: java, shortest-path

I use a two-dimensional array to store the distance of the network. `1` indicates there is connection between two nodes, `0` indicates there is no connection:

```
     A     B    C   D

A    0     1    1   0   

B    1     0    0   1 

C    1     0    0   1

D    0     1    1   0
```

[image: This is the network I want to show you according above array].

I want to use Java to find the number of shortest paths. For example, there are 2 paths from Node A to node D. Node B to node C also has 2 paths.

Comment: Your example is too simple to make any pathfinding effective. Check out Dijkstra's Algorithm for pathfinding algorithm implementation.

Comment: There is one shortest path from A-> B and A->C, and two from A->D.  It's really a simple example; it may be jazzed up by adding another node and increasing the distances a notch.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11879166/number-of-shortest-paths-between-two-coordinate-points-in-a-graph-with-constrain/11879866#11879866

Answer (score 3):

The problem you have is called "routefinding" or "pathfinding". There are a lot of stock algorithms you can use to solve it. Like for example:

- [Dijkstras algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstras_algorithm)
- [A* algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_star)

Comment: I think OP wants the number of paths, not the shortest path.